# Remoção de elemento no início de lista encadeada em C

Tags: c, lista-encadeada

Neste programa em C, estou tentando criar uma função que retire o primeiro elemento de uma lista dinâmica encadeada...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct no {
    int dado;
    struct no *prox;
};
```

As funções da lista simplesmente encadeada que implementei são as seguintes:

Imprime Lista

```
void imprimir(struct no *prim){
    struct no * atual;
    atual = prim;
    system("clear");
    printf("\nLista: ");

    while(atual != (struct no*)NULL)
    {
        printf("%d-> ",atual -> dado);
        atual = atual -> prox;
    }
}
```

Inserir elemento no início.

```
struct no * insere_inicio(struct no *prim){
    int num;
    struct no *novo;

    printf("\nInsira o elemento no inicio da lista: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);

    novo = (struct no*) malloc(sizeof(struct no*));
    novo -> dado = num;
    novo -> prox = prim;

    prim = novo;

    return prim;
}
```

Remover elemento do início. Aqui está o meu problema, pois ao invés de liberar a memória e decrementar um elemento a função está apenas apagando o dado da memória e retornando o primeiro nó como 0 (zero).

Alguém sabe dizer o que há de errado?

Todo o restante do código funciona.

```
struct no * remove_inicio(struct no *prim){

    struct no *aux = prim;

    if(prim == NULL){
        printf("Lista Vaia!");
    }

    prim = prim -> prox;
    free(aux);

    return prim;
}
```

Inserir elemento no final.

```
struct no * insere_final(struct no *prim){
    int num;
    struct no *novo;
    struct no *atual;

    printf("Insira o elemento no final da lista: ");
    scanf("%d",&num);

    novo = (struct no*) malloc(sizeof(struct no*));
    novo -> dado = num;
    novo -> prox = NULL;

    atual = prim;

    while(atual -> prox != NULL){
        atual = atual -> prox;
    }

    atual -> prox = novo;
}
```

Remover elemento no final.

```
struct no * remove_fim(struct no *prim){
    struct no *atual = prim;
    struct no *anterior;

    if(prim == NULL){
        printf("Lista Vaia!");
    }

    if(prim -> prox == NULL){
        prim = NULL;
        free(atual);
        printf("Removido do final!");
    }else{
        while(atual -> prox != NULL){
            anterior = atual;
            atual = atual -> prox;
        }
        anterior -> prox = NULL;
        free(atual);
        printf("Removido do final!");
    }
}
```

Função `main`.

```
int main(){
    int op;
    struct no *prim;
    prim = (struct no*) NULL;

    do{
        system("clear");
        printf("\n<1> - Inserir no inicio");
        printf("\n<2> - Inserir no final");
        printf("\n<3> - Remover no inicio");
        printf("\n<4> - Remover no final");
        printf("\n<5> - Imprimir");
        printf("\n<10> - Sair do programa\n\n");
        printf("Digite sua opcao: ");
        scanf("%d",&op);

        switch (op)
        {
            case 1 : prim = insere_inicio(prim);
            break;

            case 2 : insere_final(prim);
            break;

            case 3 : remove_inicio(prim);
            break;

            case 4 : remove_fim(prim);
            break;

            case 5 : imprimir(prim);
            break;

        };
    }while(op != 10);

    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Revisei o seu código. Segue abaixo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct no {
    int dado;
    struct no *prox;
};

void imprimir(struct no *prim) {
    struct no *atual = prim;
    system("clear");
    printf("\nLista: ");

    while (atual != NULL) {
        printf("%d -> ", atual->dado);
        atual = atual->prox;
    }
    printf("NULL");
}

struct no *insere_inicio(struct no *prim) {
    int num;

    printf("\nInsira o elemento no inicio da lista: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);

    struct no *novo = (struct no *) malloc(sizeof(struct no *));
    novo->dado = num;
    novo->prox = prim;

    return novo;
}

struct no *insere_final(struct no *prim) {
    int num;

    printf("Insira o elemento no final da lista: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);

    struct no *novo = (struct no *) malloc(sizeof(struct no *));
    novo->dado = num;
    novo->prox = NULL;

    if (prim == NULL) return novo;

    struct no *ultimo = prim;

    while (ultimo->prox != NULL) {
        ultimo = ultimo->prox;
    }

    ultimo->prox = novo;
    return prim;
}

struct no *remove_fim(struct no *prim) {
    if (prim == NULL) {
        printf("Lista Vazia!");
        return NULL;
    }
    if (prim->prox == NULL) {
        printf("Removido do final!");
        free(prim);
        return NULL;
    }

    struct no *penultimo = prim;
    struct no *ultimo = prim->prox;

    while (ultimo->prox != NULL) {
        penultimo = ultimo;
        ultimo = ultimo->prox;
    }

    penultimo->prox = NULL;
    free(ultimo);
    printf("Removido do final!");
    return prim;
}

int main() {
    int op;
    struct no *prim = NULL;

    do {
        system("clear");
        printf("\n<1> - Inserir no inicio");
        printf("\n<2> - Inserir no final");
        printf("\n<3> - Remover no inicio");
        printf("\n<4> - Remover no final");
        printf("\n<5> - Imprimir");
        printf("\n<10> - Sair do programa\n\n");
        printf("Digite sua opcao: ");
        scanf("%d", &op);

        switch (op) {
            case 1:
                prim = insere_inicio(prim);
                break;

            case 2:
                prim = insere_final(prim);
                break;

            case 3:
                prim = remove_inicio(prim);
                break;

            case 4:
                prim = remove_fim(prim);
                break;

            case 5:
                imprimir(prim);
                break;
        }
    } while (op != 10);

    return 0;
}
```

As mudanças que fiz foram:

- Nunca se esqueça de atribuir o resultado das funções à `prim`. Assim sendo, use `prim = remove_fim(prim);` ao invés de apenas `remove_fim(prim);`.
- Suas funções `remove_fim` e `insere_final` estavam se esquecendo de retornar o ponteiro do início da lista.
- Suas funções `remove_inicio`, `insere_final` e `remove_fim` não funcionariam se `prim` for `NULL`. Em especial no caso do `insere_final` e `remove_fim`, você até detecta a condição, mas deixa prosseguir do mesmo jeito.
- A função `remove_fim` foi possível de ser bastante simplificada, mas simplifiquei outras coisas também.

Parece que você acha que mudar o valor do ponteiro do parâmetro vai se refletir em uma mudança do valor do ponteiro passado na função. Isso não é verdade. O fato de você mudar o endereço apontado por `prim` dentro da função chamada não vai fazer o `prim` de fora (no `main`) mudar. A mudança se reflete apenas quando você muda algo no valor ou estrutura que é apontado, e não no ponteiro em si. Assim sendo, uma outra possível solução para isso seria usar ponteiros para ponteiros (o que dispensa a necessidade de atribuir os ponteiros retornados no `main`):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct no {
    int dado;
    struct no *prox;
};

void imprimir(struct no *prim) {
    struct no *atual = prim;
    system("clear");
    printf("\nLista: ");

    while (atual != NULL) {
        printf("%d -> ", atual->dado);
        atual = atual->prox;
    }
    printf("NULL");
}

void insere_inicio(struct no **prim) {
    int num;

    printf("\nInsira o elemento no inicio da lista: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);

    struct no *novo = (struct no *) malloc(sizeof(struct no *));
    novo->dado = num;
    novo->prox = *prim;
    *prim = novo;
}

void insere_final(struct no **prim) {
    int num;

    printf("Insira o elemento no final da lista: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);

    struct no *novo = (struct no *) malloc(sizeof(struct no *));
    novo->dado = num;
    novo->prox = NULL;

    if (*prim == NULL) {
        *prim = novo;
        return;
    }

    struct no *ultimo = *prim;

    while (ultimo->prox != NULL) {
        ultimo = ultimo->prox;
    }

    ultimo->prox = novo;
}

void remove_fim(struct no **prim) {
    if (*prim == NULL) {
        printf("Lista Vazia!");
        return;
    }
    if ((*prim)->prox == NULL) {
        printf("Removido do final!");
        free(*prim);
        *prim = NULL;
        return;
    }

    struct no *penultimo = *prim;
    struct no *ultimo = (*prim)->prox;

    while (ultimo->prox != NULL) {
        penultimo = ultimo;
        ultimo = ultimo->prox;
    }

    penultimo->prox = NULL;
    free(ultimo);
    printf("Removido do final!");
}

int main() {
    int op;
    struct no *prim = NULL;

    do {
        system("clear");
        printf("\n<1> - Inserir no inicio");
        printf("\n<2> - Inserir no final");
        printf("\n<3> - Remover no inicio");
        printf("\n<4> - Remover no final");
        printf("\n<5> - Imprimir");
        printf("\n<10> - Sair do programa\n\n");
        printf("Digite sua opcao: ");
        scanf("%d", &op);

        switch (op) {
            case 1:
                insere_inicio(&prim);
                break;

            case 2:
                insere_final(&prim);
                break;

            case 3:
                remove_inicio(&prim);
                break;

            case 4:
                remove_fim(&prim);
                break;

            case 5:
                imprimir(prim);
                break;
        }
    } while (op != 10);

    return 0;
}
```

Por fim, recomendo que você reveja o nome de algumas coisas, por questão de coerência. Você tem `insere_final` e `remove_fim` ao invés de `insere_final` e `remove_final` ou de `insere_fim` e `remove_fim`.

Comment: Vale lembrar que a utilização de ponteiro de ponteiro facilita a vida em outras tipos de estruturas como árvores binárias, quando é necessário saber quem é o pai do pai daquele elemento